# Mysql - Counting rows in date interval

Tags: mysql

I have the following table

```
customerID | orderID | orderDate
----------------------------------
1          |  67     | 2015-12-15
1          |  66     | 2015-10-20
1          |  65     | 2015-1-7
2          |  64     | 2014-9-6
2          |  63     | 2014-7-8
3          |  62     | 2015-1-15
```

I need to identify all the `customerID`s that have at least 3 distinct `orderID`s within a 12 month period in 2014 and 2015

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm.  You could do something like this:

```
select distinct customerId
from t
where 3 <= (select count(*)
            from t t2
            where t2.customerId = t.customerId and
                  t2.date >= t.date and
                  t2.date < date_add(t.date, interval 12 month)
           );
```

An index on `(customerId, date)` would help performance.  And, you might need `count(distinct OrderId)` in the subquery, but that doesn't seem necessary given your sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT customerID, order_count FROM (SELECT customerID, COUNT(DISTINCT orderID) AS 
order_count WHERE YEAR(orderDate) = 2014 GROUP BY customerID) AS 
table_orders WHERE order_count >= 3
```

You could change first WHERE clausule in order to change date range, i suggest you a approach counting in all 2014 year